# Firebase permissions not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

After upgrading our app from the v2 of the Javascript SDK to v3, one of our database rules stopped working.

```
"discussions": {
  "circles": {
    "$circleId": {
      ".read": "root.child('circles').child($circleId).child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      ".write": "root.child('circles').child($circleId).child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
    }
  },
  "events": {
    "$eventId": {
      ".read": "root.child('events').child($eventId).child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      ".write": "root.child('events').child($eventId).child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
    }
  },
  "users": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "$discussionId": {
      ".read": "data.child('ownerId').val() == auth.uid || data.child('userId').val() == auth.uid || data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

It just seems to be the `/discussions/users/$discussionId`. I can't read at all (unless I just return true). Is there something obvious that changed in the rules between v2 and v3?

Comment: Nothing has changed about the rules between v2 and v3. In fact, you're running the same code on the same servers, no matter what SDK you use. Can you add a code example of an operation that fails?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Here's where it fails: `discussionRef = ref.child("discussions").child("users").child(discussionId);`

Comment: Works fine on v2, but fails on v3. Permission denied.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Is there any way you can reproduce it in a jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: We're using a custom token auth, so it's not something I can throw up easily on JSBin.